# How to get accurate RGB color in blender form Adobe illustrator

Tags: rendering, node-editor, color

I have 2 question

First why the rgb color is not same when i copy the value of RGB detas from illustartor to blender RGB node in blender.

Second question. it seams okey when a use a hashtag color value but when i look my viewport and rendering is slightly different. As you can see on the image below.
so how can i get acureate RGB value in blender?

In my scene i set the World environment with pur white and film look to very-hight contraste.

Do you have ideas ?

Thanks you

[image]

Comment: In the _Color Management_, you have _View Transform_ > _Filmic_ with the _Look_ > _Very High Contrast_. Try setting _View Transform_ to _Standard_ and _Look_ to _None_. But even then, it still depends on lighting, environment etc., something you don't have in Illustrator.

Comment: You should be aware that Adobe software also has color management and so even doing something like pasting a screenshot can result with a color picker showing different colors than screen color picker.

Comment: I know, but still the bigger problem in this case is Filmic - white isn't even white or at least it has to be very very bright to be shown as RGB = (255, 255, 255). And with Standard/None it works in the default color management settings of Adobe software as you can see in my answer. Of course you can change settings there - but you can change settings in Blender as well, for example use sRGB Standard like Photoshop by default does... and since this site is to help with Blender, not Adobe...  ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you want the colors to look like in other software, other image editors etc., like Photoshop or in your case Illustrator, you should go to *Color Management* and choose *View Transform*: *Standard* and *Look*: *None* for best approximation.

I've made a comparison image to show the difference between your setting and *Standard*. Notice that even the white background is not white with *Filmic*. The other thing is, I used a *Diffuse* shader, but if you use a *Principled BSDF* for example, other aspects like reflection might have an effect on the color, too.

[image: color management]

Answer (score 0):

Well, the issue here is **gamma correction** and the HEX dialog says *(Gamma corrected)* under the hexadecimal value. Due to that it is not possible to find the 0-1RGB value in  Blender if the exact correction value, not to mention the formula, is unknown. Like 255 = FF = 1 every time but e.g. 127 = 7E = 0.402 it would seem, though, it should be near 0.5! As no fast and easy way to calculate the correct value exists, I always use hex and convert RGB to it if it is necessary. After all, hex is common now that internet is all around us.

Comment: As you can see in my answer, when he uses _Filmic_ not even RGB (255, 255, 255) = #FFFFFF = (1, 1, 1) is shown as pure white, so Gamma Correction is not the main issue.

Comment: @Gordon Brinkmann: which only proves the issue of color is never an easy one. And, just in case, check if your color intensity is 1.0

Comment: No, of course it's not easy. But he doesn't need to find a special 0-1 value, he has a hex value that he can enter in Blender, so there is no need for 0-1 values. If he enters the hex code, the RGB values adjust automatically. And when he simply uses the standard sRGB color management it fits the default Adobe setting. And why check the color intensity for that?

Comment: And that's my point: if hex gives the desired result use it and don't try to find the way to convert the RGB  to 0-1 Blender values yourself. And the screenshots suggest just that. By the way, they really could change it to the usual 0-255 or otherwise abandon it.

Comment: But his problem was that even the hex values didn't get the desired result because he was on _Filmic_ with _Very High Contrast_.

Comment: And so, together we answered his problem in full. Great job!