# Why are colors incorrect in my viewport and renders?

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, color, color-management

I am making a 2D scene in Blender, as if it were drawn in Illustrator. I have an orthographic camera pointing directly at a black object in front of a white background. The materials are very simple, but the colors are incorrect in both the viewport and render. Here you can see the materials:

[image]
[image]

And here are the values shown in the viewport when it is set to rendered shading (the same values appear in actual renders):

[image]
[image]

The hex value of the RGB node in the black material is #010b13, but it is displayed as #010102. The hex value of the RGB node in the white material is #fefefa, but it is displayed as #fdfdf4.

This effect is even more pronounced with other colors, especially darker colors. There are no lights in the scene, but I don't think that should matter as the materials are simple RGB nodes. You can see from the white screenshot that this is not the result of the camera being out of position. I'm not doing anything in the compositor.

I'm using Eevee with the following render properties:

- Display Device: sRGB
- **View Transform: Raw**
- **Look: None**
- Exposure: 0.000
- Gamma: 1.000
- Sequencer: sRGB

What do I need to change to make Blender accurately render the colors of materials?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/230404/how-to-get-accurate-rgb-color-in-blender-form-adobe-illustrator https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/92177/how-to-get-accurate-colors-with-filmic-blender https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78284/white-background-with-filmic-blender